# Cannot remove position from list, ValueError x not in list?

Tags: python, list, valueerror

I am having issues removing x and y coordinates from a list, and I keep receiving ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list. Any help would be great!

```
class PetriDish:
    def __init__(self, size=30):
        self.max_iterations = None
        self.SIZE = size
        self.all_positions = []
        self.available_positions = []
        self.world = self.create_world()
        self.counter = 0
        self.world_state = ['']
        self.all_cells = []

    def repr(self):
        return_string = '|'
        return_string += '-' * self.SIZE
        return_string += '|\n|'
        for i in range(self.SIZE):
            for j in range(self.SIZE):
                return_string += self.world[(i, j)]
                return_string += '|\n|'
                return_string += '-' * self.SIZE
                return_string += '|'
            return return_string

    def create_world(self):
        world = dict()
        self.all_positions = [(i, j) for i, j in product(range(self.SIZE), range(self.SIZE))]
        for position in self.all_positions:
            world[position] = empty_cell
            self.available_positions.append(position)
            return world

    def add_to_world(self, cell):
        self.world[(cell.x, cell.y)] = cell.symbol
        self.all_cells.append(cell)
        self.available_positions.remove((cell.x, cell.y))
```

I tried listing the x and y coordinates so the available positions can be removed, but I got the error "x not in list."

Comment: Could you post the traceback when it errors out?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nt-user/workspacefae47883/nt-test-379cb3eb.py", line 5, in test_activity1_task2
    petri_dish = activity1_task2()
  File "/home/nt-user/workspacefae47883/petri_dish.py", line 310, in activity1_task2
    petri_dish.add_to_world(Cell(position=(5, 5)))
  File "/home/nt-user/workspacefae47883/petri_dish.py", line 206, in add_to_world
    self.available_positions.remove((cell.x, cell.y))
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Where are you initializing `empty_cell` under `create_world(self)` ? and how are you using and passing to `add_to_world`? Specifically `cell`

Comment: The tuple `(cell.x, cell.y)` is not in the list.  Simple as that.

Comment: where should I add in (cell.x, cell.y)?

Comment: @John Gordon, you can stop pointing out the obvious and provide some actual help.
Considering the current posted code, I can't tell where you're calling what and how each object and list is being passed around. You'll have to step by step from creating, modifying, and removing.

Comment: @HWW Not sure how I can help further, given that the code is incomplete.  I gave the most help I possibly could under the circumstances.